# Why does nothing happen with CASE statement in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, conditional

In QGIS, Field Calculator, I am trying to fill out an existing field (target) based on values on another existing field (source), both in the same shapefile. For each value x in the source, field set the corresponding value in the target field to y.

I am trying to achieve this with a CASE statement like that:
First I tick the updated existing field and set it to target. Then I use this expression

```
case
    when "source" is 'X' then 'Y'
end
```

the target filed successfully updates to Y for each X occurrence in the source field, but all the other values in the target field are set to null.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: The software is functioning correctly (as you have instructed it to do). If you only want certain features updated, you should apply a WHERE constraint.

Comment: If you want _all_ features to get an update (or all others left untouched!), specify what `ELSE` to put into the field (i.e. for when `"source"` is not `'X'`). This may simply be what's in `"target"` in the first place!

Answer (score 5):

Use this expression:

```
case
   when "source" = 'X' then 'Y'
   else "target"
end
```

But why using a [`case`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#case) statement? It's easier with an [`if`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#if)-condition:

`if ("source" = 'X' , 'Y', "target")`